# How to connect to Jira backend?

Tags: testing, automation, jira, jira-agile

I am new to Jira. I have worked on QC, we could mass update test cases or defect. I need something similar in Jira, where I could mass update the tasks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The UI offers mass updates, there's an API. Have you looked into these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet is the [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis)

There used to be a SOAP and an XML-RPC API, but both of these have now been depricated.

You can also import JIRA issues using a CSV file: [Importing Data from CSV](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+from+CSV)

Answer (score 0):

JIRA REST API is fine, but you can also use bulk changes where you perform some operations on the list of issues filtered by query.